# Is there a resampling method that blends subsampling with the bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, resampling, methodology, subsampling

I apologize if this is an inappropriate question.  I thought of it in class the other day, and I couldn't find a specific answer in my textbooks.

I am familiar with the two basic techniques for resampling data:

1. Subsampling - drawing m observations from a dataset of size n without replacement to generate new samples (where m < n)
2. Bootstrap - drawing m observations from a dataset of size n with replacement to generate new samples (where m = n)

My question:

Is there a resampling method that blends subsampling with bootstrap?  For example, resampling with replacement of every xth observation.

If there isn't, is there a reason why this doesn't work?  Would it reduce the advantages of either method without providing any real benefit?  I thought it might strike a balance between the bias caused by non-distinct observations in bootstrap samples and the lower power of subsampling.  Is this what the .632 Rule is doing?